# Python PeeWee IntegerField - Default value of unix timestamp

Tags: peewee, flask-peewee

I would like to manage timestamps in my database using seconds since epoch using a PeeWee IntegerField rather than a DateTimeField. I know that the field definition can take a default value using a callable, but I would need to do something like:

```
timestamp = IntegerField(default=int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%s')))
```

Which I suppose is incorrect since the default value should not actually invoke the callable.

I also tried wrapping this in a function and passing that function as a callable:

```
def get_timestamp():
    return int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%s'))

timestamp = IntegerField(default=get_timestamp)
```

However this did not work either.

Is there a way to accomplish this, or do I have to retro-fit my data to use DateTimeFields instead?

Answer (score 0):

I see you mentioned that you tried wrapping your function call, I'm surprised that didn't work for you, because it appears to work fine for me:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from peewee import *
>>> db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')
>>> def get_ts():
...     return int(datetime.now().strftime('%s'))

>>> get_ts()
1448471382

>>> class TestModel(Model):
...     ts = IntegerField(default=get_ts)
...     class Meta:
...         database = db

>>> TestModel.create_table()
>>> tm = TestModel.create()
>>> tm.ts
1448471421
>>> ts_from_db = TestModel.get(TestModel.id == tm.id)
>>> ts_from_db.ts
1448471421
```

The reason you need to wrap it is because the default param takes a *callable*, and if you pass just the result of a function call, it interprets it as just another static value.